# Cleaning up workspace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I had a project that I was working on locally which was using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) as its repository.

I removed the project both locally and from VSTS.

Now I want to add a new project to a fresh new repository on VSTS but I keep getting this error:
[image]

Strange thing is I removed the workspace that was pointing to that project. Clearly, there's a reference somewhere. How do I clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below options:

#### Option 1: check if the workspace you are working contains the TFVC repo which you deleted

In Source Control Explorer -> manage workspaces -> edit the workspace you are working in -> if it contains the deleted TFVC repo -> remove the related working folder -> then checkin the changes again.

[image]

[image]

#### Option 2: check the pending changes and undo the changes which are out of the new TFVC repo map directory

In Pending Changes -> check if there contains the files/folders out of your new TFVC repo map directory -> if yes -> undo the changes which are out of the map directory -> checkin the changes again.

[image]

---

To **map a new workspace with TFVC repo**, you can follow up steps:

Source Control Explorer -> workspace -> Add -> Such as name the workspace as stage -> select your TFVC repo as source control folder -> specify a new directory (non-exist or empty) as local folder -> OK -> click Yes for workspace modified.

[image]
[image]

Now switch the workspace as the new created stage, then make changes and checkin, it should successful now.

[image]

Comment: Where's repository info kept in VS? I'm opening a new project that has the same name as the one I deleted. But it's a brand new project that has never been checked into a repository. When I open it, VS tells me it's connected to a repository on VSTS. When I follow your instructions above, I don't see a workspace configured for it.

Comment: If the TFVC repo you deleted both locally and remotely, you just need to remove the related workspace as option1 said. If you still can not checkin changes after removing the workspace, can you add related screen shots?

Comment: In the option1, I mean remove the useless folder (not workspace). If you already removed the workspace in using, please add a new workspace as the way I added in the last part of my answer.